# Python script through socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, execute

Hello I have a socket setup and I want to send python commands to be executed on the second computer. So far I can send the command `s.send('print "hello world"')` and with `m.recv(1024)` on the second machine. Can I do something like `x = m.recv(1024)` and then on the next line just an `x` to execute what has been received? Please note I have the sockets setup and running with one machine as the server and one as the client. But I have never been sure if I have been using `recv` and `send` correct because I have had no way of testing them.

Thanks

Comment: You can but make sure you encode and decode if you use Python3. Also look up the function eval() maybe that will help ;)

Comment: Did you try using the `exec()` function?

Comment: You can test them on the same machine using different ports.

Comment: Not something that you can do with fabric?

Answer (score 0):

If you use eval you can execute python code as a string:

```
eval('print "Hello world"')
```

This will print Hello world.

To directly print the input in Python 3 (**!**):

```
eval(m.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

Python 2:

```
exec(m.recv(1024))
```

**!** Like Peter Wood said in the comment, you have to be careful with what you receive; everybody that has access to your server can send *any* code they want, they could create files just by sending code.

Make sure only **you** have access to it, and to be on the safe side, make a blacklist of functions or even better, a whitelist.

Comment: Obviously you need to be careful what you receive.

Comment: @PeterWood included it, didnt think about that!

Comment: How can you be sure the content of incoming packet?

Comment: @dsgdfg Im not sure you can be. I did some testing last night and im guessing that you still accept the incoming packet, but then you search it for malicious functions before you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using python 2.x, use the exec function:

```
x = m.recv(1024)
exec(x)
```

And in case of python 3.x, use the eval function:

```
x = m.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
eval(x)
```

Do note that this wouldn't allow you to run commands with having a character count > 1024 (which is highly unlikely). Also, you need to be careful what you pass into these functions.

Comment: So what should I be careful for?

Comment: The `eval` and `exec` functions can be used to execute malicious code on the server, if the client sends such code through a request.

Comment: The command could do anything; search your machine, send email, delete data, turn up the volume control, open your web browser to some loud website, anything.

Comment: On Python3 you have to decode x first before using eval.